# schedule email with sendgrid python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sendgrid, email

I am using python module of sendgrid (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) to send transactional emails. I need help with the syntax to send the email at a scheduled time.
The general sendgrid documentation asks to modify json as "{ “send_at”: 1409348513 }". I believe this json is not directly accessible in sendgrid-python. I need syntax for doing equivalent thing with the python library.

My current code is equivalent to the one copied below. It would be great if some one can suggest how to modify this code to schedule it at a particular time         e.g. datetime.dateime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

```
import sendgrid    
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Email, Content, Substitution, Mail
import urllib2 as urllib

def send_email_custom():    
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=myApiKey)        
    from_email = Email(sendEmail)
    to_email = Email(custEmail)
    reply_to_email = Email(receiveEmail)
    content = Content("text/html", "Introduction")
    mail = Mail(from_email, subject="Hi!", to_email=to_email, content=content)
    mail.personalizations[0].add_substitution(Substitution("_firstName_", firstName))
    mail.set_template_id(templateId)
    try:
        response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    except urllib.HTTPError as e:
        print(e.read())
        return False
    if response.status_code >=200 and response.status_code < 300:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I would suggest posting this on the github repo instead of SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[send_at](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/mail_example.py#L42) is a component of the `personalizations` Object, so you can define it at that level, allowing you to set distinct sending times for each recipient/personalization set.

If you don't need that, you can also set it [at the top mail level](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/mail_example.py#L95).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Comment: can you display the code that works? i been running very similar code with scheduling not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be able to do that by following [this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python#without-mail-helper-class) example. You can specify all of the raw fields you need.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a completely different approach. It is directly populating it in the json. I was thinking that there should be some intuitive function such mail.send_at() kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Exact code solution:

```
mail = Mail(from_email, subject="Hi!", to_email=to_email, content=content)
mail.send_at = SendAt(1461775053) # Time is specified in UNIX form. 
# This takes advantage of Sendgrid's inbuilt email scheduler
# but you can't schedule more than 72 hours in advance.
```

This removes the need to deal with personalizations for send time.

Source: line 308 of https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/main/examples/helpers/mail_example.py

Posting this for those who Googled their way here in 2022 or later.